# Count number of true and false condition in spark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am coming from a MATLAB background, and I can simply do this

```
age_sum_error = sum(age > prediction - 4 & age < prediction + 4);
```

This will count the number of `age` values for which the `prediction (+4/-4)` is true, I want to do something similar in spark data frame.

Say that below is my spark data frame

```
+--------------------------+
|age | gender | prediction |
+----+--------+------------+
|35  |  M     | 30         |
|40  |  F     | 42         |
|45  |  F     | 38         |
|26  |  F     | 29         |
+----+--------+------------+
```

I want my result to look something like this

```
+------+----------+
|false | positive |
+------+----------+
|2     | 2        |
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the condition, and then aggregate the result by summing up the **`1`s** and **`0`s**:

```
df.selectExpr(
    'cast(abs(age - prediction) < 4 as int) as condition'
).selectExpr(
    'sum(condition) as positive', 
    'sum(1-condition) as negative'
).show()
+--------+--------+
|positive|negative|
+--------+--------+
|       2|       2|
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a lot more code than matlab, but here's how I would do it.

```
import numpy as np

ages = [35, 40, 45, 26]
pred = [30, 42, 38, 29]
tolerance = 4

# get boolean array of people older and younger than limits
is_older = np.greater(ages, pred-tolerance) # a boolean array
is_younger =  np.less(ages, pred+tolerance) # a boolean array

# convert these boolean arrays to ints then multiply. True = 1, False = 0. 
in_range = is_older.astype(int)*is_younger.astype(int) # 0's cancel 1's

# add upp the indixes that are still 1
senior_count = np.sum(in_range)
```

Hope this helps.